# Firefox throwing error while reading #hex color codes inside inline SVG

Tags: html, svg

This doesn't happen on Chrome, but it does happen on FF and MS Edge, at least.
In FF, when you try to paint an svg inside of an CSS `url()` or `object` tag, if the svg contains an #hex color like `#FF0000`, it will crash. Let me show you an example:

```html
<p>Not using # colors</p>
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><svg version='1.2' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' width='70px' height='70px' viewBox='0 0 100 100' xml:space='preserve'><circle fill='red' cx='50' cy='54.7' r='15.72'/></svg>">
  No SVG UTF8
</object>

<p>Using #hex colors (won't show on FF)</p>
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><svg version='1.2' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' width='70px' height='70px' viewBox='0 0 100 100' xml:space='preserve'><circle fill='#FF0000' cx='50' cy='54.7' r='15.72'/></svg>">
  No SVG UTF8
</object>
```

Why does it happen? Is there any other way in SVG to write those colors?

Comment: This is because `#` is a special character in URI scheme and that it needs to be encoded. To do so, in javascript, you can use `encodeURIComponent(yourString)` method.

Comment: @Kaiido Actually that fixes the problem but this is strange because for example, spaces don't need to be encoded... why does the # do? and only on non-webkit browsers...? strange!

Comment: No it's not strange, `#` is used as a fragment delimiter in URI scheme, space is not.

Comment: Also note that your data header may fail in some IE versions (IE10 if I remember correctly), `'data:image/svg+xml; charset=utf8, ' + encodeURIComponent(svgData);`is bullet proof. Also, you don't need to pass the xml header in your dataURI, it's already in the data header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a hash character in a URL is reserved to indicate the start of a [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).

You need to URL encode the # as %23.

It's a Chrome bug that it does not enforce this rule or indeed parse URLs correctly.

Comment: I would even recommend encoding any special characters : if I do remember correctly, IE also has a problem with `"` characters.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly believe that, you are doing something wrong with attributes of `object` tag. I just removed some attributes and made it simple.

```html
<object type="image/svg+xml">
  <svg version='1.2' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' width='70px' height='70px' viewBox='0 0 100 100' xml:space='preserve'>
    <circle fill='#FF0000' cx='50' cy='54.7' r='15.72' />
  </svg>
  No SVG UTF8
</object>
```

In this case, it works without any problem.

Also, it is not necessary to have `object` for embedding svg code. You can simply write it in html file.

```html
<svg version='1.2' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' width='70px' height='70px' viewBox='0 0 100 100' xml:space='preserve'>
  <circle fill='#FF0000' cx='50' cy='54.7' r='15.72' />
</svg>
```

You may refer [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Adding_vector_graphics_to_the_Web) for additional details.

---

If you are trying to use svg image as `data url`, first you need to encode your image using some tools hosted by sites like [mobilefish](http://www.mobilefish.com/services/base64/base64.php).

```html
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPScxLjInIHhtbG5zPSdodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZycgeG1
sbnM6eGxpbms9J2h0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsnIHg9JzBweCcgeT0nMHB4Jy
B3aWR0aD0nNzBweCcgaGVpZ2h0PSc3MHB4JyB2aWV3Qm94PScwIDAgMTAwIDEwMCcgeG1sOnNwY
WNlPSdwcmVzZXJ2ZSc+CiAgICA8Y2lyY2xlIGZpbGw9JyNGRjAwMDAnIGN4PSc1MCcgY3k9JzU0
LjcnIHI9JzE1LjcyJyAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg==">
  fallback
</object>
```

Comment: the problem is when you try to use it as `data:image/...` Try to load it inside of a background using `url(data:image/...)` like explained at the bottom of this article:  https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Comment: why not use tools given by your browser ? You probably have a console, which will grant you access to the global `encodeURIComponent` and its little sister `encodeURI` methods.

Comment: @Kaiido. Thanks, I was not aware about that functionality.